The OS reoot it self automatically
Iam using ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and it is rebooting it self automatically from times times to times. The reboot append mostly when the baterry is low and i plugin the AC adapter, some times it append when the baterry is at 100 percent and olso when plugin adapter is off even when the battery is fullly charged, other times when it reboot is when i take out of the sleepy mode.
The computer is not overheating and thermal paste is fine.
Some thing that i tried was to update the grub config file in /etc/default/grub with the following parameters
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off", another was to install the laptop-mode-tools but no one worked.
This problem does not append when i use windows. I test with other ubuntu based OS like neon, kubuntu and debian and all have the same problem.
Before install ubuntu i used the linux mint 21.1 and there was no problem.
I'm using a Toshiba laptop portege-R700-188, intel core I3 M370 2.40GHz with 8 GB of RAM.

After the system comes up again, the terminal command sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex will show the system logs leading up to the crash /shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the -b -1 option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do sudo journalctl  --list-boots, read man journalctl. For more journalctl help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username). Do you have swap? free will tell you.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Swap space must be contiguous, not fragmented. Read man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab.

@waltinator i tried it now and seems that there is no problem in the logs. The PC does not overheating. I don't think it's a sudden power outage because it works fine when i use Windows and the PC is more warm when i use it, but never reboot it self. the swap memory is active.
